# Pandas casting to upper case produces an extra row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:
df:

```
id   name
1    abc
```

I do:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.upper()
```

I get a duplicate row:

```
id    name
1     ABC
nan    ABC
```

What is going on?

Comment: unable to reproduce

Comment: could you do `del df` and run it again? I get the correct output.

Comment: Post your `df.to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the observed issue is not reproducible in an isolated code example.  What is shown in the question indicates that the procedural code is correct.  Therefore, there is a problem with input data that is not depicted.

This following MCVE ([How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) shows that there is no problem:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1], 'name': ['abc']})
print df
df['name'] = df['name'].str.upper()
print df


python mcve.py
   id name
0   1  abc
   id name
0   1  ABC
```

The example above shows an input DataFrame of

```
id   name
1    abc
```

Which maybe is not a DataFrame?